# Pygame: Is there a way of scrolling the 'coordinate system' of a white-filled display without setting a background image?

Tags: python, scroll, pygame, background, screen

I have a game display on which I used the `blit`-function to display a flight path as well as a drone. The flight path starts from the right side and goes beyond the left side of the display.

The game display is filled white and what I want is to move my drone via pressed keys from right to left along the flight path (which is just a set of contiguous lines connecting random points).

I want the 'coordinate system' of my display to move/scroll so that you can see where the flight path ends. At the same time I want my drone to maintain a static position during that scrolling, e.g. stay in the middle of the screen while it follows the flight path.

Does anybody know a function that allows me to achieve that? All I found in forums and on YouTube seemed rather complex and required one to have set a background image first. I just want the white-filled screen to scroll while I move my drone to the left to follow the red flight path. Below is what I coded so far.

Thank you a lot in advance for any advice!

```
import pygame
import pygame.gfxdraw
import random
import sys


white = (255,255,255)
display_width = 1200
display_height = 700

game_screen = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('gameScreen')

the_drone = pygame.image.load('drone.png')


X=1000
Y=350

p1=[X, Y]
p2=[X, Y]
p3=[X, Y]
p4=[X, Y]
p5=[X, Y]

pointlist = [p1, p2, p3, p4, p5]

limit1=1000
limit2=850


for i in pointlist:
    i[0] = random.randrange(limit2, limit1)
    limit1-=300
    limit2-=300
       
for i in pointlist:
    if i == 0:
        i[1] = random.randrange(200, 600)
    else:
        range = i[1]-1
        i[1] = random.randrange(range-100, range+100)
    
def flightpath(pointlist):
    pygame.draw.lines(game_screen, (255, 0, 0), False, pointlist, 3)
    
    
def drone(x,y):
    game_screen.blit(the_drone,(X,Y))   
    
    
def game_loop():
    global X, Y

    gameExit = False

    while not gameExit:
        
        for event in pygame.event.get():
        
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()    
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()  #checking pressed keys
        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            X -= 0.5
        if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            Y -= 0.5
        if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
            Y +=0.5 

        game_screen.fill(white)
        
        flightpath(pointlist)
    
        drone(X,Y)        
                 
        pygame.display.update()
        
game_loop()
pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi to be hones I don't really understand your Code but I got it working like that:

```
import pygame
import sys
import random


# init window
def init():
    pygame.init()

    pygame.display.set_caption("Drone Game")
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
    return screen


# make closing the window possible
def escape():
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()


# draws all objects on screen
def draw(screen, f, y_pos):
    screen.fill((50, 50, 50))
    for y in range(20):
        for x in range(5):
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, f[y][x], (x * 100, (y * 100) - y_pos, 100, 100))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (250, 0, 0), (240, 240, 20, 20))  # drone
    pygame.display.update()


# creates background
def field():
    f = []
    for y in range(20):
        f.append([])
        for x in range(5):
            f[y].append((random.randint(200, 255), random.randint(200, 255), random.randint(200, 255)))
    return f


# combines all functions
def main(screen):
    f = field()
    y_pos = 500
    while True:
        pygame.time.Clock().tick(30)
        escape()
        y_pos -= 1
        draw(screen, f, y_pos)

# starts program
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(init())
```

I hope it works for you. :)